# Unity C# 'set sprite position to mouse pointer' makes sprite clip through other sprites

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

(sorry if formatting or anything else is incorrect, have been using stackoverflow for quite a while, never asked a question before. Plus, I'm new to unity and c#)

I can't post images but here's a link to an imgur

https://i.stack.imgur.com/02mOg.jpg

(I'm sorry I have lots of trouble describing things and I think the image will help)

I have a simple code for a circular sprite with a circular spritemap that is attached to a spring, and when I hold the sprite, drag it back, and release my mouse, the object flies in the opposite direction to where I dragged it back to (almost angry birds like launch). But, when I hold the sprite, I am able to clip it through other sprites on my level, and even out of bounds. The ball is floating and the play is supposed to be able to drag and launch it in any direction

I have tried setting the break force of the spring to a pretty low level, so the ball doesn't launch if I pull it back too far, but the ball still follows my mouse when I drag it around, and when I release it after the spring breaks, the ball just falls down.

Also, I tried limiting the radius of the spring by limiting it's length. But, it didn't work.

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using UnityEngine;

            public class LaunchScript : MonoBehaviour
            {
              public Rigidbody2D rb;
              private bool isPressed = false;
              public float releaseTime = 0.15f;

                private void Update()
                {
                    if (isPressed)
                    {
                        rb.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                    }
                }
                // Start is called before the first frame update
                void OnMouseDown()
                {
                    isPressed = true;
                    rb.isKinematic = true;
                }

                // Update is called once per frame
                private void OnMouseUp()
                {
                    isPressed = false;
                    rb.isKinematic = false;
                    StartCoroutine(Release());
                }
                IEnumerator Release()
                {
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(releaseTime);
                    GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().enabled = false;
                    this.enabled = false;
                }
        }
```

My expected results were: the ball would follow the mouse and be able to drag back, but it wouldn't clip through the green ground blocks, the basket, or the border blocks (blocks used to keep ball from flying out of bounds).
My actual results were: I could drag the ball to any poin to the screen, including straight into the green ground and out of bounds.

Comment: So are you saying when you drag the ball with your mouse, it is able to "no clip" through the terrain? Have you added a collider to your ball and the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinematic rigidbody collider can detect collision only with rigidbody collider **(collider with non-kinematic rigidbody)** in non-trigger mode.

From Unity [Manual: Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html):

> Even when immobile, kinematic rigidbody colliders have different behavior to static colliders. For example, if the collider is set to as a trigger then you also need to add a rigidbody to it in order to receive trigger events in your script. If you don’t want the trigger to fall under gravity or otherwise be affected by physics then you can set the IsKinematic property on its rigidbody.

Try to play with isKinematic (for example reverse enabling/disabling or remove it) and disable isTrigger. And don't forget about colliders and rigidbodies on your ball and environment.

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I ended up just limiting the circumference of the spring, and working based off of that, as if I made the ball non-kinematic, it would have weird glitches (flying around randomly, and not flying in the intended direction) when I tried to pull it back.

Comment: I also did disable isKinematic when pulling it back, as that also affected the spring and movement of the ball. So now, when the mouse is down and it is on the ball, the spring is disabled, until the mouse is released. That way, the movement is fluid and works

Comment: Glad to help you